# During csv export the double quotes are wrong written by OutPutStream

Tags: string, csv, export-to-csv, outputstream, double-quotes

I m exporting a CSV with the below implementation.
The output is fine for all the Csv Names except "application" tag.
The double quotes are changed and the data becomes corrupt as it cannot be imported back.

I m not sure if String.getBytes is modifying application values or once the data is written by OutPutStream.write object, the application values are changing.

Expected CSV Output should have Application value as [xx,"yy/zz"]
But My CsvFile Output for Application is [xx,yy/zz"]"

### aInOutputStream.write(lFinalCsv.getBytes(("UTF-8")));

```
@Provider
@Component
@Produces("text/csv")
public class CSVMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter
{
 @Override
    public void writeTo(Object aInObject, Class aInClass, Type aInType,
            Annotation[] aInAnnotations, MediaType aInMediaType,
            MultivaluedMap aInMultivaluedMap, OutputStream aInOutputStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {

/*
lFinalCsv String has the following text- 

securityDomain,originHost,routeId,application,modifiedDate,active,description,modifiedBy,realm,distributionList,priority,smProvState
,p,sample,"[xx,"yy/zz"]","August 29, 2018 02:19 PM",true,,smadmin,o,[],2,NEW
*/

aInOutputStream.write(lFinalCsv.getBytes(("UTF-8")));
```

}

Expected CSV Output should have Application value as [xx,"yy/zz"]
But my CSV output has Application as - [xx,yy/zz"]"